# Ensime for Emacs stuck on "Initializing Analyzer. Please wait..."

Tags: scala, emacs, ensime

When I try to start Ensime for Emacs it stucks on "Initializing Analyzer. Please wait..."
I have scala and sbt in my PATH. I also tried to add

```
(setq
ensime-sbt-command "/usr/local/bin/sbt"
sbt:program-name "/usr/local/bin/sbt")
```

to my init.el
without luck
I use MacOS

Comment: Are you using stable or testing? I have no problems with stable ```;; Ensime stable
(use-package ensime
  :ensure t
  :pin melpa-stable)```, I neither I had to add those settings to my init.el.

Comment: I have this line: `(use-package ensime :ensure t :pin melpa-stable) (require 'ensime)` so I belive I use stable